# multiple form created in single js file. How to validate single form field validation on form submit in ant design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Forms are using ant design.I have two forms in same .jsx file. When i click form submit it validate the both form fields. I don't want to validate both forms at a time.I want to validate single form at a time. 
For example,

```
export class form extends Component { 
    form1submit(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
      this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      console.log(values)
        if (!err) {
          alert("Form1 validated")
        }
      });
    }
    form2submit(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
      this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      console.log(values)
        if (!err) {
          alert("Form2 validated")
        }
      });
    }
    render(){
    return(
    <Form onSubmit={this.form1submit.bind(this)}>
        <FormItem label="Code">
                {getFieldDecorator('code', {rules: [{ required: true,
                 message: 'Please input product code!' }],})(
                  <Input />
                  )}
              </FormItem>
     <ButtonAnt type="primary" htmlType="submit">Save</ButtonAnt>
    </Form>
    <Form onSubmit={this.form2submit.bind(this)}>
        <FormItem label="Code">
                {getFieldDecorator('code', {rules: [{ required: true,
                 message: 'Please input product code!' }],})(
                  <Input />
                  )}
              </FormItem>
     <ButtonAnt type="primary" htmlType="submit">Save</ButtonAnt>
    </Form>
    )

    }
}
```

How to validate separate button form submit? If anyone has solution post

Comment: What's in 'this.props.form' ?

Answer (score 6):

You can manage multiple forms through specifying fields in `validateFields/validateFieldsAndScroll` like

```
this.props.form.validateFields(
  ["email", "firstName", "lastName"], // << validate these form fields only
  (err, values) => { // the rest remains the same...
    if (!err) {
      console.log(values);
    }
  }
);
```

Source: https://ant.design/components/form/#validateFields-return-sample

---

**Update**: From v4 on, `validateFieldsAndScroll` may be replaced to [`scrollToField`](https://ant.design/components/form/v3#Replace-validateFieldsAndScroll-with-scrollToField).

Answer (score 2):

the `this.props.form` is attached to parent of to forms in this case is `form` component so when you want to check validation two form is checked.

**Solution 1**

if the items of each form is different you could check the `err` to find which item of form is invalid

```
 this.props.form.validateFields((err, values))
```

for example if you have item `code` in form1 but not in form2 and in `err` you find `code` you know form1 is invalid.

**Solution 2**

if items is not different between forms you could extract two forms in different components some thing like this :

```
import Form1 from './Form1'
import Form2 from './Form2'

class FormParent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        this.form1ValidateStatus = this.form1ValidateStatus.bind(this);
        this.form2ValidateStatus = this.form2ValidateStatus.bind(this);
        this.state = {form1Validation:false,form2Validation:false);
}
form1ValidateStatus(state){
    this.setState({form1Validation:state));
}

render(){

    return <div>
        <Form1 onChange={this.form1ValidateStatus}/>
        <Form2 onChange={this.form2ValidateStatus}/>
    </div>
   }
  }
```

now in in each form when something change first validate form then call `this.props.onChange` , forexample if in form1 some input change first validate form1 and then call `this.props.onChange` of form1 , if it's valid pass `true` and if it's invalid pass `false` . finally you know validation of each from from state.

Comment: Please explain it properly. I have two forms with different fields. At that time how to validate fields in single form on single submit